# Drawing transparent triangle using opengl and GestureImageView in its background

Tags: android, imageview

I need to make a Frame of Triangle shape. And GestureImageView will be the background of that Triangle Frame. Triangle With only solid borders. So that user can zoom in and zoom out the image inside the  triangle. 
Any Help ?

I have made GestureImageView. Only thing is needed is Triangle Transparent Frame. Please help ?

Following is the code

```
public class TriangleActivity extends Activity implements android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    private static final String TAG = TriangleActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int Coordinates_In_A_Vertex = 2;
    private static final int Vertices_In_A_Triangle = 3;
    private static final int Bits_In_A_Byte = 8;
    private static final int Bits_In_A_Float = Float.SIZE;
    private static final int Bytes_In_A_Float = Bits_In_A_Float / Bits_In_A_Byte;

    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private FloatBuffer vertices;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    /*
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.triangle);
        glSurfaceView=(GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        //glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);

        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(this);
//      glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
//      glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

    }

    /*
     * Called when the activity is resumed.
     * The activity is resumed whenever it is being presented to user (from the background).
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        glSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    /*
     * Called when the activity is paused.
     * The activity is paused whenever it is placed into the background. Various things can cause this (pressing the home button, receiving a phone call, turning off the display, etc.).
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        glSurfaceView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glColor4f(0.64313725490196f, 0.77647058823529f, 0.22352941176471f, 1);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface changed! width = " + String.valueOf(width) + ", height = " + String.valueOf(height));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface Created!");

        width = glSurfaceView.getWidth();
        height = glSurfaceView.getHeight();


        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1);
        //New Changes
//      gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
//      gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
//              GL10.GL_FASTEST);

         //gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
//       gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
//       gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
//       gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
         //End

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Coordinates_In_A_Vertex * Vertices_In_A_Triangle * Bytes_In_A_Float);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        vertices.put(new float[]
                { 
                    0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.5f, 1.0f,
                    1.0f, 0.0f
                }
        );

        vertices.flip();

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have code of opengl for making triangle. it is covering the whole AVD. I tried code for making it transparent. But then the result become blank.

Comment: I need output like this. Check the follwing link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/110333747/triangleFrame.png